# GUITexture disapears when I add a transform position & quaternion.identity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, transform, instantiation, quaternions

I'm trying to create a health system for my 2d asteroid shoooter. I have the health icons instantiating now using:

```
Transform newHealthIcon = ((GameObject)Instantiate(healthIconGUI.gameObject)).transform;
```

However, when I try and set it's transform position and rotation the texture becomes invisible and no longer shows.

```
Transform newHealthIcon = ((GameObject)Instantiate(healthIconGUI.gameObject, transform.position, Quaternion.identity)).transform;
```

Here's the full code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour {

    public int startingHealth;
    public int healthPerIcon;
    public GUITexture healthIconGUI;
    private ArrayList healthIcons = new ArrayList();
    public int maxIconsPerRow;
    private float spacingX;
    private float spacingY;

    void Start () {
        spacingX = healthIconGUI.pixelInset.width;
        spacingY = healthIconGUI.pixelInset.height;

        AddHealth (startingHealth / healthPerIcon);

    }

    public void AddHealth(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Transform newHealthIcon = ((GameObject)Instantiate(healthIconGUI.gameObject, transform.position, Quaternion.identity)).transform;
            newHealthIcon.parent = transform;

            int y = Mathf.FloorToInt(healthIcons.Count / maxIconsPerRow);
            int x = healthIcons.Count - y * maxIconsPerRow;

            newHealthIcon.GetComponent<GUITexture> ().pixelInset = new Rect(x * spacingX, y * spacingY, 1, 1);

            healthIcons.Add (newHealthIcon);
        }
    }

    public void ModifyHealth (int amount) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding `becomes invisible`, did you have the correct layers set up in the game? Could be that something just overlaps the sprite which has a higher Z-Order or something. You should play inside the inspector to see what you have to change (position, rotation, layer?) to make the sprite visible. Did you check that the values for `y` and `x` make sense? Because in `y`, you have `Mathf.FloorToInt(healthIcons.Count / maxIconsPerRow);` but `healthIcons.Count` is already an `int` and `maxIconsPerRow` is an `int` (so flooring it is useless), so if `maxIconsPerRow > healthIcons.Count` then `y = 0`.

Comment: ah ok ill have a play and see if thats what it is. and Im following a tutorial on this to do it. I think that is to set the row the health icon spawns on. so at the moment it returns 0, so the next icon spawns on row 1. where if the health icons count is greater than the max per row then it would return 1 or higher which would cause a new row

Comment: You don't even have to set the quaternions for this. If you work on 2d. Just stick to 2D Components. Z-Ordering may be the problem as well, and don't forget the Ignore Layers, Camera can be set to ignore some Tags so make sure it is not included.

Comment: well i dont think it is an issue with layer order, as the texture seems to disappear completely and my camera has GUI Layer set to on